# NSIndexPath only retrieves first cell value

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath

I'm trying to print out the value of where the user clicked in a method that is called when a user updates the value of a `UISwitch` in some of the cells. There are four cells that have the `UISwitch` set as an accessory of the cell. I already have the infrastructure in place to check against the values of calling `[self.basicObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, but the problem is, that no matter which cell I press, the `0` value of the `NSMutableArray` that contains the titles of the four cells is called.

```
- (void)switchChanged:(id)sender cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSLog(@"self.basicObjects value: %@", [self.basicObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}
```

As a side note, as I was looking at similar questions, it also seemed important to note that `self.settingsTable` is a grouped `UITableView` with these four cells being in section 1 (0, 1, 2). The other two sections do not contain any `UISwitch` as an accessory type, it's only this section, and only this one the references the `switchChanged:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

**Edit - 7:31pm**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.5];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        // change the text to standard case
        // change text color
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.basicObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        self.switchProperty = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        cell.accessoryView = self.switchProperty;

        if ([[self.basicStatus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"YES"])
        {
            [self.switchProperty setOn:YES animated:YES];
            [self.switchProperty addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }

        else if ([[self.basicStatus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"NO"])
        {
            [self.switchProperty setOn:NO animated:YES];
            [self.switchProperty addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.objectsType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.5];
        if ([[self.objectsStatus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Setup"])
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.298 green:0.851 blue:0.392 alpha:1]; // #4CD964 (green)
        else if ([[self.objectsStatus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Not Setup"])
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.898 green:0.267 blue:0.267 alpha:1]; // #E54444 (red)
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the code that actually calls that method. Show us your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the indexPath in your action method that way. You can only pass the sender, and optionally, the event that triggered the action. You need to get the indexPath a different way. One common way is to give the switch a tag that's equal to the indexPath.row, and use that tag as an index into your array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a problem. You can't send the second parameter like this.

```
[self.switchProperty addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

I recommend that you set a tag and use it like as below.

```
[self.switchProperty setTag:indexPath.row];
[self.switchProperty addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and in switchChanged: will be...

```
- (void)switchChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"self.basicObjects value: %@", [self.basicObjects objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]);
}
```